# How can I tell when regionChange event on MKMapView is programatic or user-drag of MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview

I have an `MKMapView` with a registered delegate so I can listen for region change events **(specifically, regionDidChangeAnimated)**.  I'm looking for a robust way of telling if a region change event was the result of a user dragging the map or from a programatic `setRegion:` request.

My goal is to have an app that auto-centers the map based on a location trace, unless the user has panned the map by hand, at which point auto-centering will turn off.  Thus, I'm calling setRegion: to recenter the map view as appropriate, but I have a hard time telling if the resulting `regionDidChangeAnimated:` call to the delegate is programatic or from a user-pan.  I've tried hacking something together, but I keep running into race conditions when the user starts panning just as a location update comes in.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this problem with a boolean that keeps track of code triggered region/center changes. Not the most elegant solution, but it works like a charm. It is a shame UIMapView does not derive from UIScrollView.

init:

```
regionChangeFromCode = FALSE;
```

button action:

```
-(IBAction) butCenterPressed:(id)sender
{   
    butCenter.selected = !butCenter.selected;       
    if(butCenter.selected)  
        [self setCenter];
}
```

set center:

```
-(void) setCenter
{
    regionChangeFromCode = TRUE; //before setCenterCoordinate, otherwise this is FALSE in regionWillChangeAnimated
    [theMap setCenterCoordinate:[self calcCenter]]; //this could also be [theMap setRegion]. Works the same
}
```

and the map delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!regionChangeFromCode) //so a user did it
    {
        if(butCenter.selected)
            butCenter.selected = FALSE;
    }
    regionChangeFromCode = FALSE;
}
```

In addition to this I have an update loop that updates the location and calls setCenter. When the button is selected the map center follows, and otherwise the center is left alone.

Comment: Had this problem too. Your code is a nice solution. It's a bit hacky, but not that bad since it still reads as good English. It's just one boolean flag :)